# Installing Postgres 9.6 in centos docker

Tags: docker, centos, postgresql-9.6

I am trying to install `Postgres 9.6` in `Centos 7` docker. But unable to do that.

1. I pulled latest Centos image
2. Installed `sudo` and installed postgres using the below command

   sudo yum install postgresql-server postgresql-contrib
3. Tried running `sudo postgresql-setup initdb` and got the below error,

> Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted failed to find
>   PGDATA setting in postgresql.service

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:latest
RUN yum install sudo
```

Comment: this is Centos 7 and Postgres 9.4.1 https://hub.docker.com/r/goriparthi/centos7-postgres/~/dockerfile/ you could adapt easily

Comment: Thanks @user2915097, I need one with Postres 9.6.

Comment: Why don't use the official docker image? `postgres:9.6`

Comment: @Robert I need Centos as well..:)

Comment: Oh.. I supposed that.